Termux getting killed by my Android 12
I am running Kali NetHunter on my Android 12 with rootless installation. Every time I connect the KeX client, my Android 12 kills the background Termux.
How can I stop it?

Possibly related/dupe: Stop ActivityManager killing background Termux processes

In the Termux notification, make sure you "acquire wakelock".
If that doesn't help, the solution depends on your Android version (12 Vs. 12L).
If you have Android 12:

On Android 12, no setting exists that can be changed with adb or root to disable killing of processes using excessive cpu and users will have to manually limit the cpu usage of forked processes using commands like nice/cpulimit.

Note that taskset could also be used.
If you have Android 12L, you have to root your device unfortunately.
All the informations can be found here: https://github.com/agnostic-apollo/Android-Docs/blob/master/en/docs/apps/processes/phantom-cached-and-empty-processes.md#commands-for-android-12
My recommendation would be to upgrade to a newer Android version (or stay with Android 11 - as I do).
